# Change required information to reset user password with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am I am working on a project with Laravel 5.3, I got to a part where for the user to be able to reset his password, the boolean field `confirmed` in the users table must be `1`. For this to work, I edited the method `sendResetLinkEmail` of the file `laravel-project-name\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails.php`

Everything is working correctly as I want but I am wondering. The `vendor directory contains the Composer dependencies`, so is it a good idea to edit the file as I did ?
In case, there is better way to do the same thing, kindly share it. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: For local only projects, you should be ok to edit something in the `/vendor` file, but I wouldn't recommend ever doing that. Should you need to move the project to a new destination, you'll have to run `composer install` which will remove any modifications you made to those files. Same when cloning using `git` or similar; none of the changes from the `/vendor` directory are saved in your repo, so they won't be carried over to any copies.

Comment: Thanks, clearer now!

Comment: No problem, it's a good question that addresses an important note that lot of new Laravel users may overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just override the `sendResetLinkEmail` method in `ForgotPasswordController`

```
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        // implementation
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The vendor directory contains the Composer dependencies, so any time the Composer dependencies are updated the all the file of the vendor are refreshed and set to the default. So any previous changes are lost.

the best thing to do is to copy the method to edit in a controller and make the modifications. @ABDEL-RHMAN's answer shows how to implement it